# Additional User Data from Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, api

After looking at the user API documentation I noticed that links to the user's social accounts including GitHub profile are not included. Is there any other way of obtaining this information?

I haven't been able to find this extra user information in the API.

It [appears](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/5563516?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow) it is not available on the user entity?

Additionally, I would like to access a hash of the user's email it looks as though this was also excluded/removed from the current version of the api. Is there anywhere else it can be obtained?

Comment: You'll want to read their [help center](https://stackapps.com/help), but this might be better asked over on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)... But as with any question on an SE site, [researching the documentation is a key first step](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Comment: Cross-site MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306015/why-are-links-to-social-media-and-github-not-appearing-in-the-se-data-dump but doesn't have an answer

Comment: I've started a bounty on that MSE question, let's see if that can lure SE staff into a response.

Comment: hash of the user email no longer gets populated in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813740) or in the datadump. I don't know if it was ever present in the API.

Comment: If you need the email hash for research purposes you can contact the SE team but you would have to sign an NDA to obtain that data, assuming they're interested in the outcome of whatever you want to research. See for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292321/158100

Comment: MSE related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221027/158100

Comment: Really curious what reason you could want this for that's not spammy.

Comment: I'm looking for the social links - but when exploring SEDE saw that email hash was available as well. I'm not expecting/wanting to resolve these into valid email addresses. My question was more broadly why is this data missing from the api - is there anywhere I can get it from?

Answer (score 7):

This information is not available in the public API.

---

Some additional comments...

The user email is [private](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144665/179419); it is not available to the general public. This is in keeping with standard (EU at least) data privacy and protection laws, c.f. [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation).

I can't think of any reason why the general public should have access to every user's email address, even if the email is hashed. The user ID serves the same purpose as a hashed email in a much more friendly way.

If your intention is to break the hashes then I don't think it's appropriate for you to have access to this information (see also [the principle of data security](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/principle-7-security/)).

Comment: They ask about the *hash of user email* which is a field that was available in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813740) but is now no longer populated. Don't go accusing the OP of breaching your privacy ...

Comment: I haven't @rene. There's more than enough information available about me on SE for anyone to be able to track me down if they're willing to pay a small amount of money. I've said that 1) the email is private 2) there's no need to have the hashed email given that the User ID serves the same purpose better and 3) I can't think of a non-malicious usage for the hashed email. Have you considered the reason why the email hash is no longer populated?

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that it was available in the query engine and expected that it would be available on the user object itself. I didn't expect to be able to break the hash - I was hoping to be able to track these hashes over time to understand how often people are changing their emails.